# Analyze to play audio file (mp3) into multiple parts which has completed sentence

Tags: android, ios, audio, avaudioplayer, audio-processing

I have a mp3 file (supposed that is conversation in English).
Ex:

- People A: **Hello. What your name?**
- People B: **My name is Linda. Nice to meet you**
- People A: **... so on**

I want to play this audio file into multiple parts. ***Each part have completed sentence***.

Ex: I click play audio, I want that expected audio player **will play the sound *"Hello."* and stop** (because it's a completed sentence). Next, I click play, it will **play the sound *"What your name?"*** (also completed sentence with full meaning) **then stop**. It repeats continuously until end of audio.

I have no idea how to deal with this problem. What terms or "search key" should I need to google to solve this problem. Any idea will be appreciated. Thank in advance.

*P.s: I want to make an audio player on iOS. It's very nice if there is some suggested resources to solve this problem on IOS platform*

Comment: one ways to create an array of starting and ending positions of clips you want to play. then you can toggle the play/stop

Comment: @MurtazaHussain thank for your suggestion but the thing I want to do that "how to create that array?" I mean how I know when the audio file have just play the sound (that sound is an completed sentence). I think that It must have an algorithm to do that but I don't know how to find it :(

Comment: my solution is based on preloaded audio file, from which you can extract audio seek position before hand. Yeah you have to some algo for the dynamic thing